# jQuery boxy Question

Tags: jquery, boxy

i using a jquery boxy to call my captche overlay:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()    {
    var zahl1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
    var zahl2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*31);

    //$("#cap").html("Wie viel ist "+zahl1+" + "+zahl2+"? <input type='text' id='answer' />");

    $("#shortbutton").live("click", function()  {
        ask();
        return false;
    });
});

function ask()
{
    zahl1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
    zahl2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*31);
    var sum = zahl1 + zahl2;
    new Boxy.ask("Wie viel ist "+zahl1+" + "+zahl2+"? <input type='text' id='answ' />", 
        ["Ok"], 

        function(val) {

            if($("#answ").val() == (zahl1 + zahl2))
            {
                $("#form").submit();
            }
            else
            {
                ask();
                return false;
            }
        },

        {title: "Captcha"}
    );
}
</script>
```

The code is a bit unclean... function call them selfts... i know... but how can i let call the "OK" event on Enter Press...

So you write the answer and press Enter... and it checks.

Have some an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could programmatically click the 'Ok' button on the box:

```
$("#answ").live("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
        $(this)
            .parent()
            .siblings("form")
            .children("input:button").click();
    }
});
```

Using `live` to listen to events no matter when the input is created.  You may have to modify selector under the check for the enter key if you have more than one input of type button (if you add a "Cancel" button for example).

Check out a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/Z2qeh/

**Note**: I tried refactoring your anonymous callback method into its own method that could be called by both the Boxy object and the `keydown` listener, but I couldn't get the interaction quite the same as clicking the "Ok" button.